# Texture coordinates don't work?

Tags: java, opengl, texture-mapping

Seriously I'm getting mad with this code, because don't work:

```
switch(particle) {
case 0:
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP);         // STONE
        glNormal3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        glTexCoord2d(1, 1); glVertex3f(x+size, y+size, 0.0f); // Top Right
        glTexCoord2d(0.5, 1); glVertex3f(x-size, y+size, 0.0f); // Top Left
        glTexCoord2d(1, 0.5); glVertex3f(x+size, y-size, 0.0f); // Bottom Right
        glTexCoord2d(0.5, 0.5); glVertex3f(x-size, y-size, 0.0f); // Bottom Left
    glEnd();
    break;
case 1:
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP);         // EARTH
        glNormal3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        glTexCoord2d(0.5, 0.5); glVertex3f(x+size, y+size, 0.0f); // Top Right
        glTexCoord2d(0, 0.5); glVertex3f(x-size, y+size, 0.0f); // Top Left
        glTexCoord2d(0.5, 0); glVertex3f(x+size, y-size, 0.0f); // Bottom Right
        glTexCoord2d(0, 0); glVertex3f(x-size, y-size, 0.0f); // Bottom Left
    glEnd();
    break;
}
```

The case 0 works fine, but the case 1 doesn't and I don't know why...
This is the image (32x32 with two 16x16 sub-textures):

[image]

Comment: Define "don't work?" What is happening on screen that you consider to not be working?

Comment: Nothing. In case 0 the application render the correct subtexture. But in case 1 directly don't render nothing. I guess the problem is in glTextCoord2d(...) but these seem correct :/

Comment: What happens if you copy the code from case 0 into case 1?

Comment: Then render correctly the stone particles :S

Comment: If case 0 is correct (is it?), then should case 1 not be `TR=(0.5, 1) TL=(0, 1) BR=(0.5, 0.5) BL=(0, 0.5)`?

Comment: Yesss! I had the bottom right coordinate wrong >.<U Thank you very much, not it works fine!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give that case 0 apparently works fine, your texture coordinates for case 1 are wrong. They should be:

```
glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP);         // EARTH
    glNormal3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glTexCoord2d(0.5, 1.0); glVertex3f(x+size, y+size, 0.0f); // Top Right
    glTexCoord2d(0, 1.0); glVertex3f(x-size, y+size, 0.0f); // Top Left
    glTexCoord2d(0.5, 0.5); glVertex3f(x+size, y-size, 0.0f); // Bottom Right
    glTexCoord2d(0, 0.5); glVertex3f(x-size, y-size, 0.0f); // Bottom Left
glEnd();
```